# In AFNetworking, what does #ifdef _SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking

This check is in my AFHTTPClient.m file. The check is actually used very frequently throughout the file and the .h file. In one case, it does this:

```
#ifdef _SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H
  self.networkReachabilityStatus = AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown;
  [self startMonitoringNetworkReachability];
#endif
```

This is still version 1.X of AFNetworking.

Thanks!

Comment: It means what it would mean in any C application,  and you should know basic C if you're planning to use Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a pre-processor statement checking that you have linked your project with the SystemConfiguration framework. If not, I believe that AFNetworking was omitting some feature, or maybe it was giving you a nice warning to make sure you don't forget to include this framework, so that AFNetworking could work as expected.

**Update**

```
#ifdef _SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H
#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <netinet6/in6.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>
#import <ifaddrs.h>
#import <netdb.h>
#endif
```

So what's going on is if _SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H is defined (internally by the SystemConfiguration framework), then AFNetworking knows that you included this framework in your project, and so it is importing a bunch of things to make use of it. Otherwise it isn't. This means that you don't have to include this framework if you don't want to.

Comment: How does one include that framework in their project? Thanks!

Comment: You can go to your project file > choose your main target > General, at the bottom there is a "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", click the plus button there to add new frameworks to your project.

Comment: I do in fact have that framework added (SystemConfiguration.framework). I suppose that it needs that framework included to enabled many features within AFNetwork, then. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes you should then #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h> where ever is appropriate in your app, probably before you import AFNetworking framework.

Comment: That should settle it, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, type 

 `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
 #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`

before importing AFNetworking.